How to display 12 Qr Code per page using tcpdf in php?
I'm not able to get the exact result after page 1 with 12 qrcodes
So far I tried this code, and I'm expecting to display 12 QR code every page.
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11);


$style = array(
    'border' => 2,
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, 
    'module_width' => 1, 
    'module_height' => 1 
);




$x = 20; 
$y = 30; 
$size = 50; 
$pdf->AddPage();
foreach($results as $row){    
    $data =  "http://localhost/test/index.php?hashcode=".$row->hashcode;
    $pdf->write2DBarcode($data, 'QRCODE,L', $x, $y, $size, $size, 
$style, 'N');
    $x += $size + 10; 
    if ($x > 140) { 
        $x = 20; 
        $y += $size + 10; 
    }
}

ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('example_050.pdf', 'I');


What happens with this code?

It display 12 qr code in first page, after that it display 1 qr code per page

Please post code of the outer loop too (which tiggers lines including the Addpage() method)

I don't have loop, maybe that's the one I'm missing for.

It's already there @life888888

I don't know where to place the loop and it's value to it, Thank you in advanced.
